# PySpark JSON Schema Error related to input_file_name()

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.3.2.3.1.4.0-315.

Below are my pyspark script and its outputs:

```
mydf=spark.read.schema(myschema).option("multiline","true").option("mode","PERMISSIVE").json("/user/testuser/test1.json")
mydf.select(col("id"), input_file_name()).show()
+----+--------------------+
|  id|   input_file_name()|
+----+--------------------+
|null|hdfs://name01/use...|
+----+--------------------+

mydf.select(col("id")).show()
+--------------------+
|                  id|
+--------------------+
|b6xt5479e-41e8-482..|
+--------------------+

mydf=spark.read.option("multiline","true").option("mode","PERMISSIVE").json("/user/testuser/test1.json")
mydf.select(col("id"), input_file_name()).show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  id|   input_file_name()|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|b6xt5479e-41e8-482..|hdfs://name01/use...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

So the symptoms are:

1. The dataframe could not return the top-level nodes when it was bound by a specified schema and also included input_file_name().
2. The specified schema may not be perfect but still worked if input_file_name() was not needed. The second output showed that, when the dataframe did not include the input_file_name(), it was able to parse at least top-level nodes according to the specified schema.
3. When no schema was specified (the dataframe used the schema inferred from itself so there was no conflict), the input_file_name() did not cause any problem.

My parsing script is bound to the schema so I have to specify one. My question is why input_file_name() made the parsing fail.